# customize opentok video window

Tags: javascript, opentok

I want to be able to see the subscribe window bigger an in the bottom i will like to publisher in a small window. just like Google hangouts

```
var apiKey = ;
  var sessionId = ;
  var token = ;

  var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);

  session.connect(token, function(error) {
  var publisher = OT.initPublisher("myPublisherDiv",{width:800, height:700});
  session.publish(publisher);
  });

   session.on("streamCreated", function(event) {
    session.subscribe(event.stream);
  });

.container
  %div{id: 'myPublisherDiv'}
```

Here is an example of what I will like to accomplish

[image]

Comment: Facing same issue, if you found any solution please share.

Comment: This was done almost 3 years ago and I don't really remember how did we accomplished.

Comment: ok, thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little library that helps make this easier. You should be able to achieve that layout using that.
https://github.com/aullman/opentok-layout-js

Comment: let me try it. Thank you